# Calling startService() on a disabled service

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service that I want to use once, and once only.

After I start the service for the first time, I disable it via:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, MyService.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Calling `startService()` again will do nothing (as expected).

My question is: is there a problem doing what I want this way? The only alternative I can think of is using a flag saved in SharedPreferences.

Comment: "is there a problem doing what I want this way?" -- other than possible race conditions, I cannot think of any problems with this off the top of my head.

Comment: What possible race conditions do you have in mind? Can you think of a race condition that would not exist when using shared prefs?

Comment: "What possible race conditions do you have in mind?" -- one thread is calling `startService()` while another thread is calling the code that you have above.

Comment: Oh, in that case, there is no problem. Thanks!